# What exactly does Mat name[x] give?

Tags: c++, opencv

I stumbled over this piece of code today, and I cannot seem to figure out what the following declaration does:

```
Mat channel[3];
```

The channel[3] is used to split an image into separate channels. I am not new to programming, but fairly rusty with C++ syntax. Can someone please help me understand what this code snippet does?

Example:

```
Mat input = someimage;
Mat channel[3];
split(input, channel);
imshow("Red", channel[0]);  
imshow("Green", channel[1]);
imshow("Blue", channel[2]);
```

**Update:**

I now realize the banality of this question. Coming from C# and Java, I attempted *Mat[3] channel* to create the array, which obviously didn't work in C++. Thanks guys!

Comment: As a side note, here's the online docs for the `C++ Mat` class: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat

Comment: If you don't recognize an array declaration it's probably time to dig out your favourite book for a refresher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can't understand there?

It is an array of type `Mat` with 3 elements.
So `Mat` is just a type.

If you don't know what the syntax of declaring a array looks like, you should probably look into a basic C Book before asking here.

Comment: Ok and what exactly is wrong in my explanation that downvoting is necessary? Maybe I should take out my C++ book, because I don't know how to declare a array in C++? Poor... downvoting a correct answer without leaving a note what the downvote was for.... really poor

Answer (score 2):

`Mat channel[3]` is declaring an array of 3 `Mat` objects that are indexed from 0 to 2. It is to say, that `channel[0]` is a `Mat`, `channel[1]` is a different `Mat` and so on.

In this case, you have an image assigned to variable `input` (in the OpenCV API for C++, images are managed as matrices with the class `Mat`). You declare 3 `Mat`s in array `channel`, and then, you use the `split` function to separate the RGB channels of your input image into three different images with one channel each. Finally, `imshow` shows a window with each resulting image.

Answer (score 0):

It splits the strings into different channels.
I'm not really used to OpenCV but the Red,Green and Blue are mapped to [0],[1],[2] respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by channels?

Comment: The variable..Mat channel[3];

Comment: @Zaibis: In image processing, it's common to break down colors into Red, Green and Blue components. The combined red parts of all pixels are named the "red channel" etc.